# Are state changes reversed if the contract "crashes" during execution?

Tags: blockchain, evm

> Are state changes reversed if the contract "crashes" during execution?

I know that state changes are reversed, if the contract runs out of gas during execution.

However, are state changes also reversed if the contract crashes by execution an invalid instruction?

If the contract chrashes, how much gas is consumed? The gasLimit or gas consumed up until that point?

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to execute an invalid opcode, the transaction fails, all gas (up to the gas limit) is consumed, and the transaction is aborted. (No changes are persisted.)

Comment: Does the same happens if a transaction tries to transfer more ether value than it has?

Comment: There are multiple ways to transfer ether. If you use `send`, the call will just return `false`. If you use `transfer`, it will `revert` on failure, which means the remaining gas is returned, but the transaction is still aborted.

Comment: What if you don’t use Solidity?

Comment: I believe that the underlying `CALL` opcode just returns 0. It's up to you to decide what to do with that failure (e.g. `REVERT`).